# Magento Infortis Theme-Icon code use

Tags: magento, icons

I want to add an instagram icon to the footer of my website. 
I have created the circle and changed the colour, but I cant get the icon for Instagram to work.

[This is what it looks like at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTG61.png)

Heres the code in the Static Block;

```
<a class="first" href="#" title="Join us on Facebook">
    <span class="icon icon-hover i-facebook-w" style="background-color: #3b5998"></span>
</a>

<a href="#" title="Follow us on Instagram">
    <span class="icon icon-hover i-instagram-w" style="background-color: #c13584"></span>
</a>

<a href="#" title="Youtube">
    <span class="icon icon-hover i-youtube-w" style="background-color: #bb0000"></span>
</a>

<a href="http://twitter.com/infortis" title="Follow Infortis on Twitter">
    <span class="icon icon-hover i-twitter-w" style="background-color: #00aced"></span>
</a>

<a href="#" title="Pinterest">
    <span class="icon icon-hover i-pinterest-w" style="background-color: #cb2027"></span>
</a>
```

The Instagram icon code is;

```
.ic-instagram:before {
content: "\e22f";
}
```